# Using Boostrap template from github in a new solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, github

I'm planning to use [blur-admin](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin) bootstrap template for a new clean web application:

However, this template is found in GitHub and I'm not sure how I can add a new solution to it after I clicked the clone button. It seems that it just created a local repository in my computer.

My question is how can I create a new solution/project and add this template from github? Any detailed explanation will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think that you need to tell more what is the problem. You said below that your problem is that the source is GitHub. However, there is no difference in that to project that is not from the GitHub it can't be your problem. Just a friendly advice, just like this i don't think that you will get the answer and your question will be probably closed.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the bootstrap theme mentioned is made from Angular. Please disregard this post.

Comment: I can't. It says "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."